# Import specific rows and colums from excel to access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, import

I have a problem with import table from MS Excel to MS Access. I need to import one table from excel sheet, where table starts on row 16. It is because the first rows are used for another tables, which I don´t want to import. I don´t have permission to change anything in Excel file. Is there any possibility how could I import only the table that I want? Thank You

Comment: Yes there is a possibility.  Post your code and where you have run into problems along with examples.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use a staging temp table where you import entire spreadsheet as is and query specific records from certain columns to final tables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I try to made it. In MS Access I know, that I need to select everything from row 16. I used this query:

`SELECT  * from [Losts Delivery Date]
    WHERE NOT (SELECT TOP 15*
    FROM [Losts Delivery Date])`

But it does not work. I don´t have permission to delete top 15 rows, so that´s a problem...